# How to check pandas dataframe column value float nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe column which value is nan and is a float:

```
df['column']
```

I want to add a logic there,if df['column'] equal float nan then do something,the problem is I have no idea how to check if it is float nan ,is there anyway like:

```
if df['column'] == 'nan':
   print('hi')
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, please be precise whether you want to check if the whole column is NaN, any value is NaN, or you want to apply a logic on rows with a NaN value and a different one on rows with values other than NaN

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [2, 3], [None, 4]], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

`df`

```
    col1    col2
0   1.0     2
1   2.0     3
2   NaN     4
```

**Code**

```
df.isna().sum() > 0
```

result:

```
col1     True
col2    False
dtype: bool
```

col1 has NaN and col2 has not NaN